# IP forwarding with openvpnas server

Tags: openvpn, dmz, ip-forwarding

I have opened port with  openvpnas server. When users  join to  my  server, everyone gets  the same IP and they can  not register to my server  because the authme  plugin senses one user  for the same IP.

How can I forward users  IP to my MC server?
I have found this on the openvpn site:

> "Both the source and destination IP addresses are routed with NAT. The destination address of incoming packets is translated to the VPN IP address of the client. The source address is translated to the VPN gateway IP address of the first OpenVPN daemon of the Access Server. This means assuming a default configuration of 172.27.224.0/20 for the VPN subnet, the packets will have source IP 172.27.224.1."

Comment: I don't know anything openvpnas but a quick search doesn't look hopeful that it's a stock option. You might be able to do your own source NAT on the machine hosting the server to map the VPN_IP:PORT couplet to RAND_IP:PORT and back again, it would be a totally fake IP address but it would give your server something to grab onto. I'll have a think about it and might have a go at setting it up

Answer (score 1):

add `client-to-client` in OpenVPN server configuration file, This should enabale each client should receive a unique IP address from the VPN subnet range

Answer (score 0):

Thank  you  but  I  finally  solved  this by installing  command  line  version  of  it  from  https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install  and  opened  port  with  this  command  :  `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.2`
This  helped  me  :  [Port forwarding through OpenVPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/380646/port-forwarding-through-openvpn)?